# Z3 answer does not satisfy constraint

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm getting started with Z3 and I gave it a toy problem. The idea is for all assignments of (a,b,c), at least one of (fa(b,c) == a, fb(a,c) == b, fc(a,b) == c) must be true.

The model reports

```
[fc = [else -> And(Not(Var(1)), Var(0))],
  fa = [else -> And(Var(1), Var(0))],
  fb = [else -> False]]
```

which does not seem to satisfy the constraint for the (a=False, b=True, c=True) case, as reported in the table below.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get a solution that satisfies the constraints, like the rule presented in the second table?

```python
import pandas as pd
from z3 import Bools, Function, BoolSort, Solver, ForAll, Or

a, b, c = Bools("a b c")
fa = Function("fa", BoolSort(), BoolSort(), BoolSort())
fb = Function("fb", BoolSort(), BoolSort(), BoolSort())
fc = Function("fc", BoolSort(), BoolSort(), BoolSort())

s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll([a, b, c], Or(fa(b, c) == a, fb(a, c) == b, fc(a, b) == c)))


def tabulate(fa, fb, fc):
    mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [[False, True] for _ in range(3)], names=["a", "b", "c"]
    )
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=mi).reset_index()
    return (
        df.assign(fa=fa, fb=fb, fc=fc)
        .assign(
            fb_correct=lambda x: x.fb == x.b,
            fa_correct=lambda x: x.fa == x.a,
            fc_correct=lambda x: x.fc == x.c,
        )
        .assign(any_correct=lambda x: x.fb_correct | x.fa_correct | x.fc_correct)
        .astype(int)
    )


print(s.check())
print(s.model())

# sat
# [fc = [else -> And(Not(Var(1)), Var(0))],
#  fa = [else -> And(Var(1), Var(0))],
#  fb = [else -> False]]

print(tabulate(fb=False, fa=lambda x: x.b & x.c, fc=lambda x: x.a & ~x.b))

#    a  b  c  fa  fb  fc  fb_correct  fa_correct  fc_correct  any_correct
# 0  0  0  0   0   0   0           1           1           1            1
# 1  0  0  1   0   0   0           1           1           0            1
# 2  0  1  0   0   0   0           0           1           1            1
# 3  0  1  1   1   0   0           0           0           0            0
# 4  1  0  0   0   0   1           1           0           0            1
# 5  1  0  1   0   0   1           1           0           1            1
# 6  1  1  0   0   0   0           0           0           1            1
# 7  1  1  1   1   0   0           0           1           0            1


# Correct answer:
print(
    tabulate(fb=lambda x: ~x.a | x.b, fa=lambda x: x.b & x.c, fc=lambda x: x.a & ~x.b)
)

#    a  b  c  fa  fb  fc  fb_correct  fa_correct  fc_correct  any_correct
# 0  0  0  0   0   1   0           0           1           1            1
# 1  0  0  1   0   1   0           0           1           0            1
# 2  0  1  0   0   1   0           1           1           1            1
# 3  0  1  1   1   1   0           1           0           0            1
# 4  1  0  0   0   0   1           1           0           0            1
# 5  1  0  1   0   0   1           1           0           1            1
# 6  1  1  0   0   1   0           1           0           1            1
# 7  1  1  1   1   1   0           1           1           0            1
```

Version: z3-solver==4.8.0.0.post1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot replicate this. When I run your program, I get:

```
[fc = [else -> And(Var(0), Var(1))],
 fa = [else -> And(Var(0), Not(Var(1)))],
 fb = [else -> False]]
```

which seems to be the correct model. Note that this differs from what you're getting as it seems to swap `fc` and `fa` in your case.

It could very well be a bug that was already fixed; I'm using a freshly compiled z3 from github sources. Can you upgrade your z3 installation and see if the problem goes away?

Comment: My result is from `z3-solver==4.8.0.0.post1`. Which version is yours?

Comment: Z3 version 4.8.5 - 64 bit. But it's a fresh build from github sources. I see that they at least have 4.8.4 released: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/releases You should at least switch to that one.